# DynamoDB: Why would I be limited by the number of partition-id?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

If I've got a students and skills data, where there is already a table with student information and I want to save this many to many relationship in a new record, what would be the best PK and SK?

I tried to save:

```
PK: skill id
SK: studentId
```

but I got feedback saying I would be limited by the number of skills I can store in a single partition, and you may create a hot partition for popular skills.

I didn't understand this and it's not possible to ask for an explanation. Can someone elaborate please?

Comment: Hot partitions: this was previously a problem, but adaptive capacity makes this unlikely to be a problem in your design. I think the person giving feedback has out of date information. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/

Comment: "I would be limited by the number of skills I can store in a single partition". There is no limit to the number of PKs that can be stored in a single partition. The person is giving you potentially bad information, or at minimum they are not providing enough information.